# Count specific number of duplicates in excel

Tags: excel, vba, count, duplicates

I am working in Microsoft Excel 2013 (Windows OS).

I have a column of data as below:

```
Data
A
B
A
C
B
A
A
B
D
```

As we can see, only A appears 4 times, only B appears 3 times whilst C and D appear 1 time each.

I need a formula/method to count how many times a number of number of duplicates appears and display it in a table like below:

```
Duplicates | Number of values duplicated this many times
     4     |        1
     3     |        1
     2     |        0
     1     |        2
```

Does anyone have a way of doing this?

Comment: you can definitely acheive this in VBA (i.e the language running in the background of ms office) you can write VBA functions directly into your excel documents, you don't need visual basic. ALthough you will have to enable developer toolbar. see https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/macros/visual_basic_editor2013.php

Comment: I expected this might be the response. Unfortunately I have no VBA experience so, whilst I am willing to learn VBA if necessary, I was hoping there'd be an easier solution. Thanks for your response though @MichaelWhinfrey!

Comment: if you have any programming experience at all, VBA won't be a challenge. I only pick it up once a year to do something similar to this across mutiple spreadsheets. Always feels like I'm relearning it but after a few hours it's all over =) GL

Answer (score 2):

This might work without VBA. Assuming `Data` is in A1, enter `Count` in B1 and in B2:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A$1:A2,A2)=1,COUNTIF(A:A,A2),"null")
```

copied down to suit. Then insert a PivotTable with Count for ROWS and Count of Count for VALUES.

Result should look so:

[image: SO39241997 example]

The `null`s should be ignored and a zero count for 2 duplicates has to be inferred. The order can be adjusted to suit.

Comment: You can actually copy Col B to column C to get the count of counts. Filter out the nulls in Col B to display only relevant rows.

Comment: Copying formulas from B to C results in C having the count of counts. Then use autofilter to hide null rows.